# How to split a list of lists into dictionary key/values pairs?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following `list`:

```
is_censored = [[True, True], [False, True], [False, False]]
```

which I want to place into a `dictionary` with keys/values equal to `is_censored_1 = [True, True]`, `is_censored_2=[False, True]` and `is_censored_3=[False, False]`.

**Can this be achieved pythonically?**

So far I have this:

```
data = dict()
for i, value in enumerate(is_censored):
    data['_'.join(['is_censored', str(i + 1)])] = value
```

which yields the right result:

```
data = {'is_censored_1': [True, True], 'is_censored_2': [False, True], 'is_censored_3': [False, False]}
```

but is not that appealing to the eyes.

Comment: so, you want 3 different dicts?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal One dictionary with 3 keys, please

Comment: `{f'is_censored_{i}': v for i,v in enumerate(is_censored)}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to format the [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
{f'is_censored_{i+1}': l for i,l in enumerate(is_censored)}

{'is_censored_1': [True, True],
 'is_censored_2': [False, True],
 'is_censored_3': [False, False]}
```

---

Note: for python versions `< 3.6` use `string.format()` as in @devesh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077674/split-a-list-of-lists-into-dictionary-key-values-pairs/56077722#56077722). You can check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) for more details

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh `f-strings` support operations, so `{i+1}` would work

Comment: If you could link my answer for < 3.6, it would be helpful I guess @yatu :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehension for this, where you get both index and item of list `is_censored` using `enumerate`, then make key-value pairs accordingly!

```
is_censored = [[True, True], [False, True], [False, False]]

res = {'is_censored_{}'.format(idx+1):item for idx, item in enumerate(is_censored)}
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
{'is_censored_1': [True, True], 'is_censored_2': [False, True], 'is_censored_3': [False, False]}
```

Comment: This is a good option for python < 3.6, which don't have `f-strings`

Answer (score 1):

```
is_censored = [[True, True], [False, True], [False, False]]

res ={'is_censored_{}'.format(i+1):is_censored[i] for i in range(len(is_censored))}
```

output

```
{'is_censored_1': [True, True],
 'is_censored_2': [False, True],
 'is_censored_3': [False, False]}
```